# Start Download Headers / Curl PHP

Tags: php, curl

how can I force a download to start using curl? I want it to begin an mp3 file download from a given mp3 url. Since a simple readfile isn't working.

more specifically : What headers do I have to set, then how do I retrieve and display the audio file using curl.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide more information on exactly what you are trying to do?  You can't use a curl call to force a download on a browser.  You have to do it by setting the correct headers on a request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a look at [Kohana's Request::send_file()](https://github.com/kohana/core/blob/3.0%2Fdevelop/classes/kohana/request.php#L851); as it offers pretty much everything you're looking for (and also read [RFC 2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) but I guess no one does that nowadays).

Comment: I'm kindof a noob how exactly do i use that function?

Comment: It's not about the function, just take a look at how it defines and sends headers / packages back to client.